# Is there a way to avoid http error 405 when uploading a file in asp net core web api?

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have an AJAX form which sends data (file uploads) to an ASP NET Web API using POST. I can hit my API end point without a problem and save the files and then return an OK. When the execution finishes on the API my page now display an error saying **405 method not allowed**. I have configured CORS and allowed access to any origin also I have tried uploading the files using chrome with security disabled just to make sure its not CORS but still I am getting a Method not allowed when the code executes without a problem.

Below is my AJAX.

```
  <script>

    function uploadFiles() {    

        var fileUpload = $("#files").get(0);
        var files = fileUpload.files;
        var data = new FormData();

        for (var i = 0; i != files.length; i++) {
            data.append("files", files[i]);
        }
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",

            url: "@TempData["api"]api/Document/BulkUpload/",
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Bearer @HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetString("token")'
            },

            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: data,
            async: false,
            beforeSend: function () {
                //Before sending
            },
            success: function (messages) {
                var list = messages;
                $.each(list, function (index, item) {
                    //alertify.set('notifier', 'position', 'top-center');
                    //alertify.success('Successfully uploaded the Document');
                    alert(item);
                });

                let delay = 5000;
                let url = "/Documents";
                setTimeout(function () {

                    location = url;

                }, 5000);
            },
            error: function (e) {
                console.log(e.responseText);
                if (e.responseText == null) {
                    e.responseText = "Failed to upload Document. Contact the admin";
                }
                alertify.set('notifier', 'position', 'top-center');
                alertify.error(e.responseText);
            },
            complete: function () {
               //After sending
            }
        });

    }

</script>
```

Below is my API end point:

```
[HttpPost]
    [Route("BulkUpload")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> BulkUpload(IList<IFormFile> files)
    {
        //Errors
        List<string> Errors= new List<string>();

        var documents = files;

//Do whatever with the docs

}
```

Below are my CORS settings:

```
            app.UseCors(x => x
        .AllowAnyOrigin()
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowAnyHeader());
```

Below is my web.config file:

```
    <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
            <add name="Access-Control-Max-Age" value="1000" />
        </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

Is there anything I am doing wrong?

Comment: Hi @codeninja, could you pls tell us what is your `@TempData["api"]` value. 405 error means the server cannot find such post method by using your current url but find other http method, like get or put or delete. It is not related to cors.

Comment: That is my endpoint am storing it in the TempData. Its "https://localhost:5003/" hence following with "api/Document/BulkUpload/". It is also decorated with Post and the endpoint is hit without a problem but still the error persists. I also tried just plainly writing the endpoint URL without using the TempData but no success. Note the comment is removing the slashes from the URL

Comment: I have solved it by removing my enclosing form tags. This is bad practice but still I cant understand what went wrong. My form tag had post and enctype of multipart/form-data. Any idea why this worked? I wasnt referencing my form anywhere in my JS code

Answer (score 0):

After successful upload, you are setting the current location to the URL

> /Documents

It seems like the corresponding endpoint does not support **HTTP GET** method allowed. Allowing the **GET** method allowed to that endpoint should resolve your issue.

Comment: I have completely removed that piece of code I am just displaying an alert. The alert is getting displayed but after that I get a blank page still about the POST call saying method not allowed. I can even log the returned data that its success on the front end but yet I am still getting method not allowed